# My getResourcesDetail is failed in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to try getResourcesDetail in my /resource/[slug]/page.tsx below, but i have an error "Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')".

I try to give question mark like this "resources?.title", the error is disappear, but the title content is not show up.

I use Next JS and Sanity

```
import { getResourcesDetail } from "@/sanity/actions";

type Props = {
  params: { slug: string };
};

async function Resource({ params }: Props) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const resources = await getResourcesDetail(slug);
  console.log(resources);

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="text-white max-w-2xl">
        <div className="text-white max-w-2xl">
          <p>{slug}</p>
          <p>{resources?.title}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Resource;
```

and this is my action.ts in my sanity folder

```
export async function getResourcesDetail(slug: string) {
  try {
    const resources = await readClient.fetch(
      groq`
      *[_type == 'resource' && slug.current == $slug][0]
      {
        _id,
        title,
        downloadLink,
        "image": poster.asset->url,
        views,
        category,
        "slug" : slug.current,
      }
      `,
      { slug }
    );

    return resources;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I want the title obtained from Sanity to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Log the `resources` to the console to see whether the `getResourcesDetail` is successfully fetched the data. If it prints `null` it means the fetch returned no data. Check the query that you passed into the Sanity client, assuming that the variables `readClient` and `slug` are correctly defined and configured elsewhere in your code.

```
export async function getResourcesDetail(slug: string) {
  try {
    const resources = await readClient.fetch(
      groq`
      *[_type == 'resource' && slug.current == $slug][0]
      {
        _id,
        title,
        downloadLink,
        "image": poster.asset->url,
        views,
        category,
        "slug" : slug.current,
      }
      `,
      { slug }
    );
    console.log(resources)  <--- console.log the resources here
    return resources;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```